# Having difficulties enabling jpa repositories in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

When I want to use the autogenerated jpa repositories with the `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses=UserDao.class)` annotation
I get the following error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

This is the interface:

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User_, Long>, UserDaoCustomMethods {

    List<User_> findAllByUserName();

    List<User_>findAllByEmailAdress();
}
```

This is the custom interface it implements:

```
public interface UserDaoCustomMethods {

    List<User_> findAllByCondition(String column, String input);

}
```

And this custom interface is implemented in the concrete class UserDaoImpl (spring is supposed to pick this class up by looking for interfacename + suffix Impl

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDaoCustomMethods{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<User_> findAllByCondition(String column, String input) {
        Query query = em.createQuery("select e from user_ e where e."+ 
                column + " = :input").setParameter("input", input);
        List<User_> entities = query.getResultList();
        return entities;
    }    

}
```

what should I do? Should I annotate the Impl class as well with @Repository?

Any help would be appreciated.

kind regards,

EDIT: heres the requested POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>SeedCalendars</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SeedCalendars</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass>com.mycompany.seedcalendars.MainApp</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
        <name>Your Organisation</name>
    </organization>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>

                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-createjar</argument>
                                <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                                <argument>-appclass</argument>
                                <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                                <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                                <argument>-outdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                                <argument>-outfile</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>                            
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                            <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>  
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.4.1</version>
<configuration>
    <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
    <filesets>
        <!-- delete directories that will be generated when you 
             start the develpment server/client in eclipse  
        -->
        <fileset>
            <directory>target/classes</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileset>
    </filesets>
</configuration>
</plugin>            
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
    <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-alpha.6-1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

EDIT: heres the complete stacktrace.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
    at com.mycompany.seedcalendars.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:28)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:854)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterMetadataProvider.next(ParameterMetadataProvider.java:122)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.build(JpaQueryCreator.java:302)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.toPredicate(JpaQueryCreator.java:208)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:115)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:52)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:109)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:126)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$CountQueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:252)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
    at com.mycompany.seedcalendars.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:28)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:854)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterMetadataProvider.next(ParameterMetadataProvider.java:122)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.build(JpaQueryCreator.java:302)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.toPredicate(JpaQueryCreator.java:208)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:115)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:52)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:109)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:126)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$CountQueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:252)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 23 more
Exception running application com.mycompany.seedcalendars.MainApp
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1:59.563s
Finished at: Sat Jul 08 21:38:14 CEST 2017
Final Memory: 38M/585M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project SeedCalendars: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I would also like to add that when I remove the annotations from my mainApp class which extends Application

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration (exclude = {  DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class MainApp extends Application {
```

Then the application loads but i get the error nullpointer exception when it tries to autowire the UserDao to a classvariable after pushing a button.

Which is strange because I also happen to have a config class with the same annotations on it like so:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")})
//@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.DAOs","com.Services","com.Controllers"})
//@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"com.DAOs"})
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses=UserDao.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses=UserDao.class)
public class ComponentScanConfig {
```

So it looks like the annotations on the java main class were interfering with the annotations on the config class, but I don't get why spring isen't injecting my jpa repositories.

Comment: how you are invoking the dao/impl class?

Comment: what do you mean, in the code itself? with @Autowired, but it never gets to autowire anything because of the error above

Comment: Whats the output of `mvn dependency:tree`? The error sounds like you have some dependency conflicts. Also posting the content of your pom.xml could help.

Comment: Read the docs about how to create a [custom repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations). `UserDaoCustomMethods` isn't a valid name as per convention.

Comment: there is only a convention for the implementing class. This should end with Impl. For the custom interface itself aren't any naming conventions In the spring book of Craig walls they don't talk about the custom interface having a naming convention.

Comment: Why oh why do you name your entities witha trailng underscore? Especially given that a trailing underscore is what JPA uses for metamodel classes. This not only breaks Java naming conventions and makes code harder to read, but also makes it even more confusing by adopting a convention used by something else, in the same field. Regarding your question: when asking about an exception, **always** post the complee stack trace of the exception.

Comment: well because my good Sir, the word User also happens to be a protected SQL word that is used by the database itself, hence the added underscore. Anyway i' ll change it to something proper then.

Comment: ok i' ve added the stacktrace

Comment: That's really not a good justification. Just keep the name User for your entity, and use `@Table(name = "myuser")`to use a different table name.

Comment: Also note that your JPQL query is invalid, and that your two repository methods don't make sense, since they're supposed to find by  user name or email address, but they don't take any argument. I wouldn't be surprised if respecting the conventions, and fixing these methods, fixed the issue.

Comment: removing those 2 methods doesen't solve the problem, also the JPQL query isen't invalid, it worked perfectly fine when I was solely using hibernate. (I'm trying to get everything to work with spring now)

Comment: `select e from user_`. Your entity is named `User_`, not `user_`.

Comment: pff even after I put all those repository classes in the same package as my configuration class (the class that has ComponentScan and @EnableJpaRepositories on it ) I STILL get a nullpointer exception whenever the program wants to use the not so injected UserDao bean.... Why?!?! I seriously don't get this... UserDao has Repository on it so Spring knows this is a component it needs to scan..

Comment: i think spring changed that from User to user because spring has renamed all my tables in my database to lowercase tablenames it seems..

Comment: The exception does have something to do with query method parameters. Check that you don't have other such methods missing parameters, and put a breakpoint to identify which query causes the problem. That said, your last comment seems to indicate that the problem is in fact fixed, since you now have a different, NullPointerException. And your very last comment doesn't make sense: Spring doesn't change your code. You wrote that query, not Spring. And JPQL doesn't use table and column names. It uses entity names and field/property names.

Comment: no it isen't solved. When i put in another Dao that has no custom implementation and ask a simple print of otherDao.count() then that dao gives me a nullpointer exception as well! This Dao has no custom implementation whatsoever so it shoulden't give any problems yet it does..

Comment: System.out.println(cityDao.count()); this is the line

Answer (score 0):

Please try with proper semantics for custom repository.

https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-eight-adding-functionality-to-a-repository/

Answer (score 0):

Your methods

```
List<User_> findAllByUserName();

List<User_> findAllByEmailAdress();
```

don`t have any parameters.
It should be like

```
List<User_> findAllByUserName(String userName);

List<User_> findAllByEmailAdress(String emailAdress);
```

Hope this helps